# Coffeescript passing arguments in a function in nodejs app?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In javascript I can have a route in my nodejs app that work like this:

```
exports.hasVote(a,b) = function(err, res) {
    res(true)
}
```

Problem is when I try to do the same in coffeescript (I moved to coffeescript...). So I replaced the function above with this one:

```
exports.hasVote(a, b) = (err, res) ->
  res true
```

When I run the app I get this error:

```
error: unexpected =
```

How can I accomplish this in coffeescript and have it work just like it used to in javascript?

Comment: `exports.hasVote(a,b) = ...` is not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because you can't do it in JavaScript either. Coffee-script is just catching it at a higher level.

```
   foo() = anyThing
```

is not valid JavaScript (and therefore not valid CoffeeScript) because you can not assign a value to an invocation.